# How to navigation goback function works in React native page including Webview

Tags: react-native

I am working with Webview in React native.

Header and footer is not webview, and header includes navigation.goBack() button in it.

> 

But it is not working even footer has navigation.navigate() button which is working.
Here is my code.

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import * as React from "react";
import { ImageBackground, StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, TextInput, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import { AntDesign } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';
import { height, width } from 'react-native-dimension';
import HeaderLink from './header_link';
import Footer from './footer';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1, 
      // flexDirection: "column"
    },
});

class LinkPageScreen extends React.Component {
    render() {
        this.state = {
            url: this.props.route.params.url,
            title: this.props.route.params.title,
        };
        var linkURL = this.state.url;
        
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <HeaderLink
                    image={false}
                    imageSource={{}}
                    left={
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={ () => this.props.navigation.goBack(null) }>
                      ....
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    }
                 
                />
                <WebView
                    source={{uri: linkURL}}
                    style={{marginTop: height(12), marginBottom: height(11)}}
                />
                <Footer navigation={this.props.navigation} />
            </View>
            
        )
    }
}

export default LinkPageScreen
```

I changed navigation.goBack into navigation.navigate() but it was not working also in header.
I checked for same error on stackoverflow but webview.goback() function was there, and my problem is not like that. I am sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. Even I don't know why.
I changed the code like below.

```
class LinkPageScreen extend React.component {
   render() {
     return (
        <View>
           <WebView .... />
           <Header />
           <Footer />
      ......
```

Unbelivably it works, i just changed the order of tags between webview and header.
Anyone can explain to me why this is happening?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below:

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

const {goBack} = useNavigation();

const navigateBack = useCallback(() => {
    goBack();
}, [goBack]);
.
.
.

<TouchableOpacity onPress={navigateBack}>
 ....
</TouchableOpacity>
```